# What version of Javascript is supported in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

I'm getting started with Node.js and I'm having a hard time figuring out what version of JavaScript is supported by node which makes it difficult figuring out what features I can use. Here's what I know.

- [Node](http://nodejs.org/) uses V8
- [V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/) implements ECMAScript as specified in ECMA-262, 3rd edition
- ECMA-262, 3rd edition is [JavaScript 1.5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Versions)

Given this, I would assume I can use JavaScript 1.5 compatible code in node. However, it turns out I can use the [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/foreach), among other constructs, even though according to MDC it isn't available until Javascript 1.6 -- ECMA-262, 5th edition.

Where am I going wrong? Is there a document somewhere that details the available language features?

Comment: For a 2015 update, see [ECMAScript 6 features available in Node.js 0.12](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388885/ecmascript-6-features-available-in-node-js-0-12).

Comment: And a 05.2016 update, according to [nodejs docs](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/), they follow [JavaScript ECMA-262 specification, 6th edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) and "All ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) features are split into three groups for shipping, staged, and in progress features"

Comment: ECMA-262 is ECMAScript 5.1 is Javascript 1.8.5, see also (scroll down to specifications): https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Comment: it's not node official, but the typescript wiki _recommends_ target versions for stable node versions: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Node-Target-Mapping

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[This matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(ECMAScript)) (V8 follows the WebKit column fairly closely) seems to pretty well answer the question "what features can I use?" but I can't find a canonical answer to "what version of javascript is supported?"  As far as I can tell, the best answer is this: ECMA-262 3rd edition is supported, but many features of the 5th edition are also supported.

There's a good explanation of why V8 follows the WebKit and JavaScriptCore functionality on [this thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.javascript.nodejs/3404).

Comment: 2020 Update: See the [answer by Nate Whittaker](https://node.green/).

Comment: the wiki page is deleted

Answer (score 38):

Looks like, at some point, [node.green](http://node.green) was created to track JavaScript feature support against different Node versions.

Comment: I'm adding a note here because, on the surface, it seems node.green only lists support for ES 2015. You can adjust this by editing the URL, like so https://node.green/#ES2018, which shows support for ES9, I believe. https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-262/

Comment: Perhaps I don't know how to navigate it, but it's so confusing to me. All I need is the answer "what ES version is used in this Node version", and all I get is the features supported in every Node version

Comment: The page is divided into sections for each ES version. As you scroll down, it shows features that were introduced in each version and their compatibility with different Node.js versions

Answer (score 33):

The Node javascript version depends on which version of v8 that Node uses. Node version 0.5.1 (14 Jul 2011) and upwards use v8 3.4.10 or later, and are 5th edition ECMA-262, rather than 3rd Edition. 5th edition is equivalent to Javascript 1.8.5. See below reasons.

Between 21 May 2011 and 15 June 2011 the v8 website stopped listing v8 as implementing 3rd edition ECMA-262 and started showing 5th edition.
http://web.archive.org/web/20110521053630/http://code.google.com/p/v8/
http://web.archive.org/web/20110615102350/http://code.google.com/p/v8/

According to the v8 changelog, on the 15 June 2011 v8 changed to version 3.4.4. So that version and later are 5th edition.

According to the Node changelog, v8 3.4.10 was in Node Version 0.5.1, 14 Jul 2011, so that version and later are 5th edition ECMA-26. This does not mean that v8 versions before 3.4.10 were purely 3rd edition though, since there may have been a steady transition from 3rd to 5th through many v8 versions.

Comment: Well, even though V8 was switching to 5th edition there is no evidence of Node actually complying with it completely in versions 0.5.1+. My 0.6.12 isn't supporting Object.prototype.getOwnPropertyNames() though it's listed in ECMA262-5th 15.2.3.4.

Comment: Have to fix my previous comment as mentioned method is a static one instead of being bound to Object.protoype (which is indeed included with node 0.6.12) and thus there is no evidence of NodeJS not fully supporting ECMA262-5th ...

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [2016 blog post from the V8 team](https://v8.dev/blog/modern-javascript) which explains why this is a mess, especially since 2016 when TC39 started releasing new JavaScript / ECMAScript specifications more frequently.

If you are using Visual Studio Code ([or any editor using Language Server / LSP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68782883/1450420)) then valid values for the compilation target include such things as `es2015` (aka `es6`) and `es2016`.

The only workaround I can find to know if my version of Node supports a given version of JavaScript goes like this:

1. Find the V8 version in that particular Node either by running `node -p process.versions.v8`, or via the [Node docs](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/)
2. Find which version of Chrome corresponds to that V8 version, via [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_version_history)
3. Go to the [Kangax compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/) mentioned in the V8 blog post above, and check which features / JavaScript versions that version of Chrome supports

The result is that currently Node LTS (16.13.1), includes V8 9.4, which supports all the ECMAScript 2022 features.

Answer (score 2):

It seems as though we have been reduced to two strategies to figure out which version of Javascript node uses:

**Strategy 1:** trust in what some document somewhere says, which is wrong in many cases.  I haven't found the table which indicates the key-value pairs of which version of node supports which version of ECMAScript.

**Strategy 2:** guess-and-check.

Find a feature quoted by ES6 and "see if it fails", something like this:

```
el@apollo:~/code$ echo "console.log('blue'.includes('blue'))" > a.js
el@apollo:~/code$ cat a.js 
console.log('blue'.includes('blue'))
el@apollo:~/code$ node a.js
/home/el/code/javascript/02/a.js:1
ports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { console.log('blue'.includes('
                                                                    ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/el/code/javascript/02/a.js:1:82)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
el@apollo:~/code$ babel-node a.js
true
```

I suppose the "babel" here is a reference to the Tanakh.  What features does our version of node support?  Well, I don't know, you'll have to manually test it.  This is going to become a giant MESS.  And worse, it seems to be on purpose.