# Migrating from JavaScript to Typescript in V0.10.XX of Node.js

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am working on V0.10.XX of Node.js (Project's requirement). I am planning to migrate to Typescript. Can I migrate to TS with V0.10.39 of Node.js or I have to upgrade to the latest Node version first?

Comment: Being that TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript that in the end compiles down to plain JS, It _should_ work with anything that can run JS

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10131285), you should be fine with Node 0.5.1 and newer if you set the `target` compiler option to `es5`.