# What to use in tsconfig, commonjs, umd, or es6 module?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, tsconfig

What `module` to use in `tsconfig`, commonjs or es6?

How to make desicion? I need that output module will work in client/back sides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here we are talking about the [module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) option that will be used by typescript to determine what is the name of the module that will compile your code to the targeted version of javascript you specified with the option `target`.

So the underlying question you are asking is, what is my target ? Should I target ES3, ES5, ES6, ES7, ES8 or ... ES42 ?

---

Answer : **the compatibility**.

In 2020 you propably target `ES5` or `ES6` (which is the default value).

(You can ignore `CommonJS` because it relate to ES3 which is 99% chance irrelevant to you)

[some article](https://medium.com/computed-comparisons/commonjs-vs-amd-vs-requirejs-vs-es6-modules-2e814b114a0b)

---

If your code is made to be executed on browsers, I would recommand you to look which is the latest version supported by all your targeted browser and take the one that is supported by all.

Ex: Safari ES6, Firefox ES8, Chrome ES8 : so you choose ES6 as target so your code works on every targeted browser.

The website [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/) is usefull to know which features are supported and which are not

---

If your code is made to run on backend (node.js), look at which version of node.js is running. Every version of node have different capabilities.

You can have a look [here](https://node.green/)

[image]

---

---

Additionnal materials :

[What version of Javascript is supported in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139168/what-version-of-javascript-is-supported-in-node-js)

Comment: So, does it mean to use ES6 for modules (building npm package)?

Comment: @OPV I would personnaly target ES6. If you encounter any BUG in your tests, downgrade to ES5 but it's unlikely, nowaday every browser and node supports most of ES features. [article](https://itnext.io/why-you-should-use-es6-56bd12f7ae09)

Comment: @Orelsanpls What if my code runs in both browser and nodejs? What should I choose in that case?