# Mapping of Node.js version to ECMAScript version

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-next

Is there a mapping somewhere from Node.js version, e.g. 0.10, or 14, to the corresponding ECMAScript version, e.g. ES5, ES2020?

> As this question is closed, I can't post the solution I came up with as an answer, so it is here instead.
>
> [@bevry/node-versions](https://github.com/bevry/node-versions) includes [`fetchESVersionForNodeVersion(nodeVersion: string): Promise<string>`](http://master.node-versions.bevry.surge.sh/docs/globals.html#fetchesversionfornodeversion) which will fetch the ECMAScript version that was ratified by the time that the Node.js version was released.

Comment: https://node.green/. See also e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/5139168/3001761.

Comment: There is no such thing as a direct mapping because no single node.js version  represents a 100% transition from one version of the ECMAScript specification to a new version.  Instead, it is a gradual adding of new language features over time and over many versions.  As you've now received two recommendations for, node.green will show you the feature by feature transition between nodejs versions.

Comment: node.green is not really very useful, I find it very confusing for making a decision on which exmascript version to target given a base nodejs version.

Comment: if you googled here you probably want this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57607634

Comment: The best resource I have found so far is on tsconfig github repo, e.g.: https://github.com/tsconfig/bases/blob/main/bases/node16.json . Here you can find typescript config files for various node versions including it's corresponding javascript version (look at the target field).

Comment: @VincentPazeller if generating the right scaffolding for the various node versions is your use case, take a look at https://github.com/bevry/boundation — it's what I coded https://github.com/bevry/node-versions for

Answer (score 13):

> #### Which features ship with which Node.js version by default?
>
> The website [node.green](https://node.green/) provides an excellent
> overview over supported ECMAScript features in various versions of
> Node.js, based on kangax's compat-table.

Source: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/